# localhost:8080/hello-world returns 404 - enonic xp

Tags: content-management-system

I have created enonic project `hello-world` site. the content studio shows site URL as `/hello-world`
But when browser calls `localhost:8080/hello-world` it returns `404` error log from enonic server.

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure your *XP_HOME/config/com.enonic.xp.web.vhost.cfg* file with something like this:

```
enabled = true

mapping.a.host = localhost
mapping.a.source = /hello-world
mapping.a.target = /site/default/master/hello-world
mapping.a.idProvider.system = default
```

You can read more about it in the [official XP-documentation about vhost](https://developer.enonic.com/docs/xp/stable/deployment/config#vhost).